# Too many newlines in BeautifulSoup stripped_strings... How to get plain text formatted more closely to original html?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Using Python 2.7 and bs4, consider the following HTML snippet:

```
    <div class="pd-t10">
        <ul class="bullet-list c-body pd-b20">
            <li class="mr-t20">
            <strong>
              <em>Innerhalb Deutschlands</em>
            </strong>: 0800 100 6711</li>
            <li class="mr-t20">International: Siehe die Liste der 
            <a href="/de/support/contacts/us_support.html" fallback="Auf Englisch" target="new">geb&#252;hrenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit</a> von VMware.</li>
            <li class="mr-t20">
            <strong>Wichtiger Hinweis:</strong> Bitte halten Sie Ihre 
            <a href="/de/support/customer-number-faq.html" fallback="Auf Englisch">Kundennummer</a> bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie &#252;ber ein VMware-Konto verf&#252;gen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der 
            <a href="/account/secure/customerRegistration.do?action=existingCustomer">Profilseite</a>.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Using .stripped_strings gets the text out, but the format of printing the plain text doesn't match how the text would be displayed in a browser:

```
for x in foo.stripped_strings:
    print x
```

yields:

```
Innerhalb Deutschlands
: 0800 100 6711
International: Siehe die Liste der
gebührenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit
von VMware.
Wichtiger Hinweis:
Bitte halten Sie Ihre
Kundennummer
bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie über ein VMware-Konto verfügen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der
Profilseite
.
```

But what I'd like to see is:

```
Innerhalb Deutschlands: 0800 100 6711
International: Siehe die Liste der gebührenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit von VMware.
Wichtiger Hinweis: Bitte halten Sie Ihre Kundennummer bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie über ein VMware-Konto verfügen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der Profilseite.
```

Is there a clever way to do this that I've missed?  get_text and find_all(text=True) yield similar results...

Adding a little more detail...   Here's the thing that's confusing to me:  it seems like soup objects maintain some memory of tags even after they're removed...

if we use .unwrap() on every tag that isn't `<p>`, `<li>`, or `<br>`, foo becomes:

```
<div class="pd-t10">

<li class="mr-t20">

Innerhalb Deutschlands
: 0800 100 6711</li>
<li class="mr-t20">International: Siehe die Liste der 
        gebührenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit von VMware.</li>
<li class="mr-t20">
Wichtiger Hinweis: Bitte halten Sie Ihre 
            Kundennummer bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie über ein VMware-Konto verfügen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der 
            Profilseite.</li>

</div>
```

which still doesn't behave the way you'd expect:

```
[txt for txt in foo.stripped_strings]
[u'Innerhalb Deutschlands', u': 0800 100 6711', u'International: Siehe die Liste der', u'geb\xfchrenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit', u'von VMware.', u'Wichtiger Hinweis:', u'Bitte halten Sie Ihre', u'Kundennummer', u'bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie \xfcber ein VMware-Konto verf\xfcgen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der', u'Profilseite', u'.']
```

But if we write the unwrapped code to a tempfile, then open that as a new soup object, we get much closer:

```
[txt for txt in newSoup.stripped_strings]
[u'Innerhalb Deutschlands\n: 0800 100 6711', u'International: Siehe die Liste der \n            geb\u7aefhrenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit von VMware.', u'Wichtiger Hinweis: Bitte halten Sie Ihre \n            Kundennummer bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie \u7aefber ein VMware-Konto verf\u7aefgen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der \n            Profilseite.']
```

Now it's just a matter of replacing newlines with spaces in each list item and stripping out the extra whitespace (`' '.join(listitem.split())`).  This gives a solution to the general problem, but it doesn't explain why dumping the string & create a new soup object behaves differently than the existing soup object.

Comment: more generally, I guess I only want breaks at <p>, <li>, and <br>

Answer (score 1):

I never scrape the entire text. But have always been specific.

But since you have to do it the way you asked, then I would use simple tools like one below and would get the right solution.

Remember that I am here assuming that the data is always in this format `a:b` like in `Innerhalb Deutschlands: 0800 100 6711`

So here is what I will do with your `html`

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
text=soup.text.replace("\n:",":").replace("\n "," ")
text=text.split("\n")
text=filter(None, text) # This is to remove the empty elements
text=[" ".join(c.split()) for c in text] # To remove the extra whitespaces
for i in text:
    print i

Out[46]:
Innerhalb Deutschlands: 0800 100 6711
International: Siehe die Liste der gebührenfreien Telefonnummern weltweit von VMware.
Wichtiger Hinweis: Bitte halten Sie Ihre Kundennummer bereit, wenn Sie den Support anrufen. Wenn Sie über ein VMware-Konto verfügen, finden Sie Ihre Kundennummer auf der Profilseite.
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: The colon was coincidental, but I get your meaning.  What about cases where there is no space after the newline?
+1 for a solution for the specific case; I'm more interested in a general solution, though.

Comment: @dbl thanks for +1 - But to be honest - scraping most of the time is dynamic - there is no general solution. We always have to find some or the other pattern which we can assume not to change soon or which we find best to last long. Having said that, if you still need a generic solution then the only thing I could think of is a combination of CSS with soup. Did you ever try that?

Comment: read my edits to the original post.  found a general solution, it's just not elegant.